# Custom temp directory + Dataflow

Tags: dataflow, local.xml

I added the following to my local.xml:

```
<default>
    <system>
        <filesystem>
            <tmp>{{root_dir}}/var-instance/tmp</tmp>
        </filesystem>
    </system>
</default>
```

I'm running Magento in a multi-server environment, and `/var` is on an NFS. However, I noticed that Dataflow imports were using `/var/tmp` to store local copies of downloaded files, and that's very slow over NFS. So I created the `/var-instance/tmp` directory, and pointed Magento there.

Dataflow is correctly writing it's temp files there, however those files are not being deleted when Magento is done with them.

This might actually be two problems. 1) Maybe changing the `tmp` directory isn't a good idea; I'm open to suggestions. 2) Maybe Dataflow never deletes it's temp files, and this has nothing to do with me changing the path.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

`Mage_Dataflow_Model_Batch::_afterDelete` calls the Io Adapter's clear method (`Mage_Dataflow_Model_Batch_Io::clear`) which deletes the file. However, I was unable to find any part of the normal Dataflow Advanced Profile logic path which deletes the batch when it's done. Therefore, the batch data in the database, and the temporary file are left behind.